# linux /proc/mounts deleted, how to fix?

Tags: mount, nfs, deleted-files

I have no idea how it happened but /proc/mounts is gone

```
root# cat /proc/mounts
cat: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
```

I can no long mount NFS shares anymore either.

```
#  mount -t nfs 10.10.10.10:/backups /mnt/thing/ -v
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon May  3 16:24:58 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=10.10.10.10,clientaddr=10.10.10.11'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=10.10.10.10,clientaddr=10.10.10.11'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Reboot fixed it, thanks. I couldn't perform a reboot at the time as it was a production system, was wondering if there was anything I could do in the mean time. Reboot was the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be able to delete /proc/mounts; the proc pseudo-filesystem doesn't allow that operation, as far as I can tell.

Which probably means you've not mounted the procfs on /proc. Try doing that!

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
```